# Place labels on top of each bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data frame:

```
week          person_counts
2023-01-23    777
2023-01-30    800
2023-02-06    890
2023-02-13    766
2023-02-20    789
```

How can I plot this with labels on top of each bar?

I have the following code:
I see solutions online but most of them are solutions when plotting using the pandas function or with seaborn. How can i do this with just a matplotlib bar() plot?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,6))
ax.set_ylabel('Person Count')
ax.set_title('Persons')

ax.xaxis.set.major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
ax.bar(df.TimeStamp, df.person_counts, width = 5)

plt.xticks(df.TimeStamp)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html), and there are definitely questions on SO related to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804

Comment: seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib, and pandas used matplotlib as the default plotting backend.